# Cisco 2600 (xm) and Exchange 2013 External Access

Tags: networking, router, microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2013

I have installed and set up Exchange Server 2013 within my LAN network. I have ran into an issue accessing the ECP or OWA through the web (outside the LAN) and can't figure out why. I have made sure that the virtual directories setting is appropriate for both the ECP and OWA. The domain used externally is exchange.example.com. (Example: exchange.example.com/ecp or exchange.example.com/owa) I made sure the extra dns/name server points to my WAN IP address on my Cisco router.

However, when I go to the domain exchange.example.com to log in, I receive a message. The server at http://exchange.example.com requires a username and password. The server says level 15 access.

I am not sure if this login is referring to my router, or my Exchange Server. I do try a ECP and OWA valid login, but it never works and just refreshes back to login window. I'm not even sure what type of credentials they are seeking, or if I missed a configuration step for this.

Note: The accounts that I want to log in to access email OWA and ECP are Windows Domain Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue! This level 15 login that popped up was a Cisco router login. I received this login and not the Exchange server login because the router was never set to forward port 80 to the Exchange Server. Setting the router the port forward TCP 80 to the exchange server solved the problem.